# how to block users in squid uploading files more than 10 mb through mail

Tags: linux, squid

I installed squid in ubuntu linux.How to restrict users to uploading files using e-mail accounts more than 10mb files.

Comment: Don't do this, please.  Arbitrary attachment size limits are annoying.  I should be able to send gigs and gigs of data via e-mail if I want to and am patient enough to wait for it to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean uploading files throught webmail service.
If so, then you need to limit request header size using **request_header_max_size**.

Also you should create some URL patterns to which this rule will apply using **acl**, or it will apply to all POST requests.

try such of this piece of config

```
acl limitedpost url_regex ^http://www.somewebmail.com/mail/$
http_access allow limitedpost AND request_body_max_size 10240 KB
```

More info here : http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl
and here : http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/

Comment: could describe more how to write acl for this